Why am I experiencing Linux Python permission error errorno 13 after a power outage?
One day, I experienced a power outage at 4:00 AM.
At 8:00 AM, I connected to my Raspberry Pi and I started again a daemeon that currently is not started automatically.
sudo systemctl start getdata.service

The daemon is started but nothing is written in logging files as before.
I stopped the daemon and started this shell script manually.
bernard@raspberrypi:~/p1meter $ sh getdata.sh
/home/bernard/p1meter
FILE: ./data/Measures.2024-12-16.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bernard/p1meter/getdata.py3", line 155, in <module>
    OpenDataFile()
  File "/home/bernard/p1meter/getdata.py3", line 94, in OpenDataFile
    f = open(sFile, "a")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './data/Measures.2024-12-16.csv'
bernard@raspberrypi:~/p1meter $

I discouver that file created (append) seems to be no more writable!
So, I decide to rename output file using mv command.
When I start again my script manually, all is working correctly.
I decide to stop program and to start it again using daemon and all now is working correctly.
Question: What is happening? Why it is impossible to write to this output file?
My Python code used is:
def OpenDataFile():
    sFileDate = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    sFile = "./data/Measures." + sFileDate + ".csv"
    f = open(sFile, "a")
    f.write(sFileDate + ";" + sHeader)
    f.write("\r\n")

Shell script crashes on open() line.
After a power outage, what must I do before starting daemon without encountering some write file issues? Is there a system command to release locked file?
More information…
Every time that I stop and start again the service, it is impossible to open output file.
In service, output file is never closed because I write indefinitely in output file. The output file is only close at 12:00 PM when a new day begin.
Is there something to write in Python program to intercept stop daemon command to close properly open output file? Is there something to add in systemd config file?

it sounds like your file was open for write, and got corrupted during the power failure. most of the time if you are going to have issues as the result of a hard power-off, it will be with files that are open for write at the time.

Litlle precision - I obtain same error if I stop manually the service and if I start it again just after. In this case, I get same error without electrical issue.

Never put relative paths in code where you have no idea what your current working directory is. From what you have posted, it could be anywhere.

The errono 13 is displayed because I tried to open a file that is blocked by root because locked file is created by systemd that is, by default, started as root.
This issue occurs because systemd is started as root and Python script doesn't close open file properly.
To start Python script as simple user, I have changed documentd config file:
[Service]
Type=simple
User=bernard
WorkingDirectory=/home/bernard/p1meter
ExecStart=/bin/sh getdata.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

Now I use my first name as User.
I have modified Python script in adding following lines:
import signal
...
class Kill:
    bKill = False
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_properly)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_properly)

    def exit_properly(self, signum, frame):
        self.bKill = True
...
killer = Kill()
InitProcess()
while not killer.bKill:
    DoJob()
...
WriteAllMeasures()
CloseDataFile()

Now opened files are properly closed and file's permissions are correctly assigned for current user.
